# How to render several templates from a sub directory in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have some templates stored in my pages view directory:

Pages/settings/edit_account/
basic_info.html.erb
relatives.html.erb
contact.html.erb

I have a piece of javascript using the jquery .load function. I'm basically allowing users to click the links on a page: basic info, relatives, contact and have the information they need to see in order to make the edits show on the same page without it refreshing. It works perfectly fine if I use this path "profile_path" which is a path I have set up in my routes.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#theBasics").click(function() {
          $("#editProfileContent").load(<%= profile_path %>);
 });
```

What  I want to do though is set up more of those functions for each of the templates in pages/settings/edit_account/

This doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#theBasics").click(function() {
          $("#editProfileContent").load(<%= render 'pages/settings/edit_account/basic_info' %>);

      });
```

I could create several actions in the controller and set up routes for them or I could create a whole new controller.

But there must be a much more cleaner way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve. Can't I use 1 action for all the templates?

I can get this working if I put render 'pages/settings/edit_account/basic_info' into an action in the pages controller then in the javascipt .load function I just call the action route and it works but I can only render one template at a time.

I hope I haven't confused anyone.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to create multiple actions. Each ajax call should have its own action end point if it is loading different information, or a different view of that information.

If the only difference is in the views, you could use a single controller action, and pass in a parameter, which you can then use in the render stage of the action to control which view is used.

For example:

```
case params[:view]
  when 'contact' render 'pages/settings/contact...'
  when 'relatives' render 'pages/settings/relatives...'
end
```

etc.

and then

```
$("#dest").load('<%= profile_path({ :view => 'contact' }) %>');
```

in your javascript.

Comment: Thanks spot on. I use the case when in the action in my controller. I was wondering whether there was a rails equivalent to the php version of this because this is how I would have solved it. Thanks